# preg_match for float(with check exist fractional part)

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match("#^\d+\.?\d*$#",$number);
// 1    - return 1
// 1.2  - return 1
// 2.25 - return 1
// 1.   - return 1 - but this not full number(there is no fractional part) 
//                   and should return 0
```

I have problem with check number `1.` becouse i get `1` instead of `0`.
For solve problem i tryed use `preg_match("#^\d+\.?(?=\d)\d*#",$number);` but it not work, becouse in latter case number `1` return `0`.

Tell me please why `preg_match("#^\d+\.?(?=\d)\d*#",$number);` return `0` for number `1` and how fix it ?

Comment: Use `preg_match("#^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$#",$number);`. Your `^\d+\.?(?=\d)\d*` requires 2 digits at least.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew big thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one :

```
preg_match("#^\d+(\.\d+)?$#",$number);
```